# Wordpress Forbidden Update Pages

Tags: wordpress, permissions, ftp

I already tried to look for some solutions about this, but i didn't find any.. Maybe you guys can solve my problem.

I can't update my Wordpress page

**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /demo/myfolder/wp-admin/post.php on this server.
Apache Server at www.my-site.com Port 80**

some say to delete my .htaccess file and refresh the page. that didn't work..

Right now here's the content of my .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

I also tried "wp-admin and right click on the very folder, give permission 777"

**Internal Server Error File "/var/www/vhosts/my-site.com/httpdocs/demo/myfolder/wp-admin/post.php" is writeable by group suPHP 0.7.1**

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you have ftp access go to wp-admin and right click on the very folder, give permission 777 (if you are using Filezilla).

Comment: Recurse into subdirectories?

Comment: Internal Server Error

File "/var/www/vhosts/my-site.com/httpdocs/demo/myfolder/wp-admin/post.php" is writeable by group

suPHP 0.7.1

Comment: 777 permissions are unnecessary and very insecure. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions for the correct and secure permissions= structure.

Answer (score -1):

777 permissions are unnecessary and very insecure. See the docs at WordPress.org [Changing File Permissions « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) for the correct file/folder permission structures and how to change them with an FTP client.

If that doesn't work, ask your webhost.

Comment: The link above is almost the same as the answer below.. I don't understand it. Maybe you can give a specific answer?